# Space-optimal format for utf-8 encoded, zlib compressed list of UUIDs

Tags: text, encoding, utf-8, compression, uuid

Each UUID is followed by a JSON encoded string on the next line. One option is to hex encode each UUID, like the following:

```
4CED6DD372A64BD7A6FDBACF13FDC688
"I love cats"
517E76C0AF79411DBF05C1E54501E200
"and \"dogs\""
996EA8502AD64A6380CC6B3D9494D05A
"and llamas"
C7A139C342D54658AAA2FC1382C62A1D
"and bats"
FA633104518E4861A7BC356A47C64052
"and cows."
```

Is there a more space-efficient representation?

Also, is there an efficient alternative to JSON for unicode strings?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question. Unicode defines characters. UTF-8 is one of the encoding of Unicode, but not the most efficient (but for real reasons, especially if you work with long texts). So possibly you need a different encoder. Note: efficiency depends also on language (and zlib also depend on languages). The more information you know about text structure, the more you can compress.

Comment: The text file represents a map from UUID keys to string values. It will be saved as utf-8 text file, then compressed with zlib. The goal is to determine the space-optimal text representation for 1) the UUIDs on each line, and 2) the string values on each line. One challenge is that due to their random nature, UUIDs don't compress well, so switching to a more compact textual representation (e.g. base64), won't necessarily help with the zlib file size. The strings values can contain any valid unicode character, except line break characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you text is mostly ASCII (or also code point <= U+07FF, you can keep the file encoded in UTF-8. If you have text mostly with larger codepoints, maybe a UTF-16 file could be better.

The `"` are redundant, you can remove them and add when decompressing.

I would not use BASE64, if you can use a UTF-8 text file: you can encode 2 bytes in 1 to 3 (or 4 see later) text characters. See e.g. Wikipedia article of UFT-8 on how to encode/decode, but you may also use standard function (from codepoint/number to character and inverse). So read 2 bytes of UUID (so a number between 0 and 65535), and interpret it as Unicode code point. Convert this character to UTF-8 representation. The decompression is similar. This is most efficient than BASE64.

I would just do a small change: I would add 32 to the 2-byte value of (a part of ) UUID, so that you will not have control characters (and new-line character) in output. UTF-8 can encode also numbers above 65535, just it requires new byte, but still more efficient then BASE64. As alternative you may use some escape character.

Note: UUID have fix length, so you may skip the new line after UUID.

Note: the output text is UTF-8 like, but not a 100% valid UTF-8 text. Normally this difference should not matter (just test it): we encode (and UTF-8 algorithms allow it) surrogate code points, but surrogate codepoints should not be included in correct UTF-8 text.

This will compress the text. Then you should check with zlib if the difference is noticeable, with realistic cases.